# module.exports undefined when requiring sequelize Model class, what could be a correct structure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I'm following the sequelize documentation to have a simple sqlite3 db, in the docs every thing seems to be in one file but with routes I need those classes in different places.

My index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const applyApi = require("./src/routes").applyApi;
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: "sqlite",
  storage: "./database.sqlite",
});

class User extends Model {}
class UserFavourite extends Model {}

User.init(
  {
    // Model attributes are defined here
    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      // allowNull defaults to true
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    passwordDigest: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    // Other model options go here
    sequelize, // We need to pass the connection instance
    modelName: "User", // We need to choose the model name
  }
);

UserFavourite.init(
  {
    movieRefId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    movieTitle: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    moviePosterPath: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    seen: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    },
  },
  {
    // Other model options go here
    sequelize, // We need to pass the connection instance
    modelName: "UserFavourite", // We need to choose the model name
  }
);

User.hasMany(UserFavourite);

const app = express();
applyApi(app);

app.get("/", (req, resp) => {
  resp.send("test");
});

(async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", error);
  }
  await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
  app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("Server started on port 3001");
  });
})();

exports.models = {User, UserFavourite};
```

And then I import the classes let's say in the user router that for now it's just a test with a hardcoded user to create:

```
const userRouter = require("express").Router();
const models = require("../../../index");

userRouter.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(typeof models)
  console.log(models)
  try{
    const user = await models.models.User.create({
      firstName: 'Bla',
      lastName: 'BLABLA',
      email: 'a@a.a',
      passwordDigest: 'lklkl'
    })
    console.log(user)
    res.send("OK")

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    res.status(404).send("Error")
  }
});

exports.userRouter = userRouter;
```

As you can see I have to do models.models.User etc. If try

```
const { models } =require("../../../index");
```

or

```
const models = require("../../../index").models;
```

models is undefined in the console log and I have no clue at this point why, with the snippet from the file above the console.log comes as { models: { User: User etc... } } and works fine: models.model.User.create({userdata})

The model class from my understanding doesn't need to be instantiated, like user = new User(), it's just class methods. I don't mind using it like it is at the moment but I can't understand what's happening here, can anyone explain me what's going on?

My second question would be then, what's a good folder structure with sequelize to have every class in it's own folder and just import it, I'm thinking something like in Rails that the controllers know about the models, to be honest I'm "translating" a Rails API that I have to better get used with NodeJS.

The only thing I found on stackoverflow is this link https://github.com/sequelize/express-example but it's 3 years old and apparently not applicable with sequelize v6, and also I don't quite understand what's going on in the models folder.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I decided to reply to my question after some trial and error, hopefully it will be helpful to others.

As Mayank said, that looks good for a model file, but we can simplify it a lot by using the sequelize CLI.

I've decided to install it manually (npm i -g sequelize-cli).

If you generate models through the CLI you'll also have an index.js file and a migration file. Since you cannot pass more than one argument and no associations apparently, you could just do something like `sequelize model:generate --name User --attributes name:string,email:string` etc... and then manually change BOTH the model and the migration with the desired fields. Make sure to also change the config file automatically generated to your desired DB settings.

Then after you run `sequelize db:migrate` the first time, in your routes or wherever you need the models you can just require the 'db' object that's being exported from the file index.js within the models folder.

Seems a lot easier, though too bad the docs don't cover any of this, hope this helps others!

Thanks,

Alex.

Answer (score 0):

A good folder structure will be something like this.

```
├── models
│   ├── user.js
│   ├── userfavourites.js
│   ├── index.js


//example model

'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const user = sequelize.define('user', {
   movieRefId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    movieTitle: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    moviePosterPath: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    seen: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT   
    },
  });
  user.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return user;
};
```

Now where ever you want to use your model.

```
const models = require('<path>/models');
const UserModel = models.user;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go, how come the freezeTableName though? Also know how come the weird behaviour with the require?

Comment: If you don't want to use plural names for your table. We use freezetable name.